# What is the difference between Promise.any() and Promise.first()?

Tags: promise

They look almost identical but [have different descriptions such as on the book You Don't Know JS](https://rileygelwicks.gitbooks.io/you-dont-know-js/async%20&%20performance/ch3.html).

Don't they both try to get the first resolved answer (or get notified of the first successful resolve), without caring about any rejection?

Comment: Only any exists? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/first

Comment: I don't quite understand why that book mentioned `.first()` and `.any()` separately

Comment: Note (emphases mine) *"**Some** Promise abstraction libraries provide these"*, *"how we **could** define `first`"*.

Answer (score 2):

The article you refer to provides an implementation of `.first()` and it also provides definitions of both `.any()` and `.first()`:

> - `any([ .. ])` is like `all([ .. ])`, but it ignores any rejections, so only one needs to fulfil instead of all of them.
> - `first([ .. ])` is a like a race with `any([ .. ])`, which is that it ignores any rejections and fulfils as soon as the first Promise fulfils.

This definition of `any` seems different from [the one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) that is currently in stage 3 for EcmaScript. The quoted definition of `any` seems to await *all* promises to be settled. The returned promise will only be a rejection when *all* those were rejected, but will fulfil, if *at least* one promise fulfilled -- ignoring the rejections.

The phrase *"so only one needs to fulfil instead of all of them"* is somewhat confusing, but the comparison with `.all()` is not about *when* the result settles, but in which conditions it will *fulfil*.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) there is no `Promise.first`.

The book You don't know JS has mentioned:

> While native ES6 Promises come with built-in Promise.all([ .. ]) and Promise.race([ .. ]), there are several other commonly used patterns with variations on those semantics:

Native ES6 only supports `Promise.any` and `Promise.all`. [Promise.any is not supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any).

`Promise.any` will resolve as soon as anyone promises from the array of promises resolves. It is also called `latch` first one to resolve wins.

`Promise.all` will resolve when all of the promises from the array of promises resolves. While there is no specific order in which promises will resolve. If any promise gets reject then Promise.all will reject the reason for the rejected promise. This is also called a `gate` main promise that can't get resolved until all the promises get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The difference seems to be that `Promise.any()` as defined by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) will `reject` if none resolve and `Promise.first()` as implemented in the book you have linked wont be rejected at any point. Other wise I can't see any difference.